# This Android code has no error but just refuses to work. Crashes when I click next

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

I am trying to change the image displayed on clicking the button. However, when I click the button the app just stops working. In the console, I receive an IllegalStateException saying it could not find method in a parent or ancestor context. Can't find the error. Here's the java code

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

public void clickFunction(View view)
{
    ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    myImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.angrybird3);

}
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Here is the XML page:

```
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Choose Bird"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#00FF7F"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/angrybird2"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:text="Next"
        android:background="#87CEFA"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/nextBird"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
        android:onClick="clickFunction (MainActivity)" />
```

Comment: Always post the exception (stack trace).

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. When I created the function in MainActivity.java and linked it through Design View to the button, this is reflected in the activity_main.xml. However, it does so like this "android:onClick='clickFunction(MainActivity)'". So, I tried leaving just the function name and it worked.